# How to "build" a Sveltekit app that can still fetch data after building it?

Tags: node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm currently developing an app with Sveltekit. I want to build it and I've followed the steps from the [Sveltekit's website](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/building-your-app). I'm using the [node adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node) and I've installed it. The problem is, after building it, the page is not retrieving the data from the API. The page is as if to be a static page.

Perhaps I did something wrong or perhaps I missed something? I've run `npm run build` and it returned no error.
[image: Build report]

If I just enter the `npm run dev` command, everything works completely fine. The page will load the data from the API.

I'm going to provide the codes down below.

svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

import path from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    
    vitePlugin: {
        inspector: false,   
    },
    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            out: 'build',
            precompress: false,
            envPrefix: '',
            polyfill: true
        }),
        prerender: {
            entries: ['/', '/dashboard', '/dashboard/[slugs]']
        },
        alias: {
            // these are the aliases and paths to them
            '$src': path.resolve('./src')
        }
    }
};
export default config;
```

+layout.ts

```
export const prerender = true;
```

+page.ts

```
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';

export const load = (async ({ fetch, params }) => {
    const res  = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/indikator_mutu`);
    const item = await res.json();

    return { item };
}) satisfies PageLoad;
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `npm run build` creates the static files, ready for production. On which server are you running/executing these files? I assume that you only open the HTML file, without starting a server? In this case, please run `npm run preview` once the `npm run build` finished.

Comment: At this time, I'm running on shared hosting which has limited access like SSH let alone run that command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`prerender`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender) renders pages to static files. This should only be used on pages that are *not* supposed to be dynamic. By setting it in the top `+layout`, nothing will be dynamic.

(This option is not to be confused with [`ssr`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr); even without pre-rendering SvelteKit will by default server-side render pages on the first request.)

Comment: If I want to make the page to be dynamic, how to achieve that?

Comment: Just don't set `prerender`.

Comment: That's it? Alright I'm gonna try again